# Alias name issue in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was trying to write a query for the SQL Server sample DB Northwind. The question was: "Show the most recent five orders that were purchased by a customer who has spent more than $25,000 with Northwind."

In my query the Alias name - "Amount" is not being recognized. My query is as follows:

```
select top(5) a.customerid, sum(b.unitprice*b.quantity) as "Amount", max(c.orderdate) as Orderdate
from customers a join orders c
on a.customerid = c.customerid
join [order details] b
on c.orderid = b.orderid
group by a.customerid
--having Amount > 25000     --throws error
having sum(b.unitprice*b.quantity) > 25000  --works, but I don't think that this is a good solution
order by Orderdate desc
```

Pls let me know what I am doing wrong here, as I am a newbie in writing T Sql. Also can this query and my logic be treated as production level query?

TIA,

Comment: Does top(5) Gets You the Most Recent 5 Records.. ?

Comment: @BhuminVadalia The `TOP(5)` on its own not, but together with `ORDER BY OrderDate DESC`, yes. The ordering puts the most recent ones first, then the top cuts the result to output just the very first 5 of them.

Comment: You can't use Order by OrderDate in your query because OrderDate column not in you group by columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known limitation in SQL Server, at least, but no idea if it's a bug, intentional or even part of the standard. But the thing is, neither the `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses accept an alias as part of their conditions, you must use only columns from the original source tables, which means that for filtering by calculated expressions, you must copy-paste the very same thing in both the `SELECT` and `WHERE` parts.

A workaround for avoiding this duplication can be to use a subquery or cte and apply the filter on the outer query, when the alias is just an "input" table:

```
WITH TopOrders AS (
    select a.customerid, sum(b.unitprice*b.quantity) as "Amount", max(c.orderdate) as Orderdate
    from customers a join orders c
    on a.customerid = c.customerid
    join [order details] b
    on c.orderid = b.orderid
    group by a.customerid
    --no filter here
    order by Orderdate desc
)
SELECT TOP(5) * FROM TopOrders WHERE Amount > 25000 ;
```

Interesting enough, the `ORDER BY` clause *does* accepts aliases directly.

Comment: When I am executing both our queries, the results seem to be different. My query is returning 5 rows, while yours is returning 2 rows. As I am seeing it your internal or subquery is similar to mine. Only the filter is applied outside to the subquery. Unable to understand this difference. Also you were right about Order By clause accepting the alias directly (for e.g. OrderDate in the above query and in mine also).

Comment: Ups, yeah, my fault, I just realized. Problem is the `TOP` inside the subquery, it must really be in the outer one, because it would take the first 5, then remove the lower amounts, while in fact it should first remove the lower amounts, then take 5 from the remaining ones. Will fix the top issue. Yes, the inner query is a simply a copy-paste of yours, without the filter and the top (moved to the outer query), but otherwise the same.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the aggregate in the query you have.  This all has to do with the order in which a SELECT statement is executed. The syntax of the SELECT statement is as follows:

```
SELECT
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
ORDER BY
```

The order in which a SELECT statement is executed is as follows.  Since the SELECT clause  isn't executed until after the HAVING clause, you can't use the alias like you can in the ORDER BY clause.

```
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT
ORDER BY
```

Reference Article: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm

Comment: Ahz: Thanks for the info. This probably explains as to why the Order By clause can be used directly with aliases, as already mentioned by Alejandro

Answer (score 0):

You must use `Where b.unitprice*b.quantity > 25000` instead of `having Amount > 25000`.
Having used for aggregate conditions. Your business determine your query condition. If you need to calculate sum of prices that have above value than 25000, must be use `Where b.unitprice*b.quantity > 25000` and if you need to show customer that have total price above than 25000 must be use `having Amount > 25000` in your query.

```
select top(5) a.customerid, sum(b.unitprice*b.quantity) as Amount, max(c.orderdate) as Orderdate
from customers a 
JOIN orders c ON a.customerid = c.customerid
join [order details] b ON c.orderid = b.orderid
group by a.customerid
having sum(b.unitprice*b.quantity) > 25000  --works, but I don't think that this is a good solution
Order by Amount
```

Comment: mehdi lotfi: Thanks for the information. But your query is not returning any rows. While my earlier query returned 5 rows. I am checking again. Also, is there no way of using the Alias - "Amount" while further filtering my query. I mean, everytime I need to write - "sum(b.unitprice*b.quantity)" instead of Amount. Thnks

Answer (score 0):

The **`Having`** Clause will works with aggregate function like SUM,MAX,AVG..

You may try like this

```
SELECT TOP 5 customerid,SUM(Amount)Amount , MAX(Orderdate) Orderdate
FROM
(
      SELECT A.customerid, (B.unitprice * B.quantity) As "Amount", C.orderdate As Orderdate
      FROM customers A JOIN orders C ON A.customerid = C.customerid
                       JOIN [order details] B ON C.orderid = B.orderid
) Tmp
GROUP BY customerid
HAVING SUM(Amount) > 25000
ORDER BY  Orderdate DESC
```

Comment: I think your Having clause is wrong... it tries to SUM a Amount column from projection but there is no Amount column in projection..

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar: I am getting the following error: "Column "Tmp.Orderdate" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: @XMarshall I have updated the query. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

The question is little ambiguos.

> Show the most recent five orders that were purchased by a customer who
>   has spent more than $25,000 with Northwind.

Is it asking to show the 5 recent orders by all the customers who have spent more than $25,000 in all of their transactions (which can be more than 5).

The following query shows all the customers who spent $25000 in all of their transactions (not just the recent 5).

- In one of the Subquery BigSpenders it gets all the Customers who spent more than $25000.
- Another Subquery calculates the total amount for each order.
- Then it gets rank of all the orders by OrderDate and OrderID.
- Then it filters it by Top 5 orders for each customer.

--

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT C.customerid,
               C.orderdate,
               C.orderid,
               B3.amount,
               Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY C.customerid
                   ORDER BY C.orderdate DESC, C.orderid DESC) Rank
        FROM   orders C
               JOIN
               --Get Amount Spend Per Order
               (SELECT b2.orderid,
                       Sum(b2.unitprice * b2.quantity) AS Amount
                FROM   [order details] b2
                GROUP  BY b2.orderid) B3
                 ON C.orderid = B3.orderid
               JOIN
               --Get Customers who spent more than 25000
               (SELECT c.customerid
                FROM   orders c
                       JOIN [order details] b
                         ON c.orderid = b.orderid
                GROUP  BY c.customerid
                HAVING Sum(b.unitprice * b.quantity) > 25000) BigSpenders
                 ON C.customerid = BigSpenders.customerid) X
WHERE  X.rank <= 5
```

Comment: OneZeroPundit: I am getting the following error on compiling: "Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'orders.CustomerID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Ambiguous column name 'orderid'."

Comment: @XMarshall Updated the answer. Check now. These queries are not tested  as I dont have access to databases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have that schema at hand, so table' and column' names might go a little astray, but the principle is the same:

```
select top (5) ord2.*
from (
    select top (1) ord.CustomerId
    from dbo.Orders ord
        inner join dbo.[Order Details] od on od.OrderId = ord.OrderId
    group by ord.CustomerId
    having sum(od.unitPrice * od.Quantity) > $25000
    ) sq
    inner join dbo.Orders ord2 on ord2.CustomerId = sq.CustomerId
order by ord2.OrderDate desc;
```